# cucumber cannot load such file -- rails (LoadError)

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-4

I've installed cucumber-rails gem into new Rails 4 application following https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-rails#installation

But when I try to run it error occurs:

```
biske@biske:~/bla$ cucumber

cannot load such file -- rails (LoadError)
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in 'require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in 'rescue in require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in 'require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-rails-1.3.1/lib/cucumber/rails.rb:3:in '<top (required)'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in 'require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in 'rescue in require'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in 'require' /home/biske/bla/features/support/env.rb:7:in '<top (required)'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in 'load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in 'load_code_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in'load_file'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in 'block in load_files!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in 'each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in 'load_files!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:183:in 'load_step_definitions'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in 'run!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in 'execute!'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.4/bin/cucumber:13:in '<top (required)' /usr/bin/cucumber:23:in 'load' /usr/bin/cucumber:23:in '<main'
```

This error complains about 7th line from features/support/env.rb file, which is:

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
```

What could be problem here?

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue after upgrading cucumber-rails version up to 1.3.15.

First of all regenerate your cucumber configs (especially if you have updated some gems recently):

```
rails g cucumber:install
```

If it does not help try to run cucumber within a bundler using command:

```
bundle exec cucumber
```

or more convenient and technically identical command (works in my case on rails 4.1.1):

```
rake cucumber
```

Learn more about "bundle exec" command prefix: [Use bundle exec rake or just rake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275885/use-bundle-exec-rake-or-just-rake)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was that the file env.rb that I had in features/support, was requiring a file it shouldn't have, or that didn't exist.

So, check features/support/env.rb edit out as many requires as you can and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

cd into the `features` folder then try to run `cucumber your_feature_name.feature`

Comment: any idea why this makes it work, but running the same features file from the directory level up doesn't?   Also when I do that, it runs the feature, but doesn't find the step-definitions which are in subfolder of features :-(