# What is the difference between bin/rake and bundle exec rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between using bin/rake and bundle exec rake.
And which is one preferred style?

```
bin/rake db:migrate
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: + when do we need bundle exec and when not?

Comment: Check this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275885/use-bundle-exec-rake-or-just-rake#answer-8275912

Comment: Click here for more clarification on
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean

Answer (score 5):

`bundle exec` executes a command in the context of your application.
As each application can have different versions of gem used. Using bundle exec guarantees that you use the correct versions.

I use `bundle exec` always instead of rake because i have multiple applications running on my system.

Try to use `bundle exec rake db:migrate` always.

You can learn more about it here [Official documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.16/man/bundle-exec.1.html)

Answer (score 4):

`bin/rake` is a kind of *stub* for the rake command from bundled Gems. It has exactly the same function as `bundle exec rake`. See http://bundler.io/v1.14/man/bundle-install.1.html and search for `binstubs` for more about stub. And also note that `bin/rake` and `bin/rails` are stubs generated by Rails, which are different in code from the stubs generated by bundler. However, they all serve the same purpose and have the same function.

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 options on a typical system:

1. `bin/rake db:migrate`
2. `rake db:migrate`
3. `bundle exec db:migrate`

The first option is simply calling the path to the `rake` program, whose launcher can be found in the hidden `/bin` folder. This launcher is usually just a symlink to the program's content found in your `/.rvm` directory. You can find its original location by executing `$ which rake`, which will give you something like `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3-p481@devonzuegel/bin/rake`.

By default, the second option is essentially the same as the first on most systems. It's what is called an alias, which is basically just a shorthand command for some other program. This is defined somewhere in your shell settings as something like `alias rake='/bin/rake'`. It's possible that this alias is pointed to a different program on your machine though, so check that before taking my word for it.

When you use `bundle exec` you're telling bundler to ensure that only the gems and their specified versions from your `Gemfile.lock` are loaded. This will only work if you're in a directory that contains a `Gemfile.lock` or whose parent/grandparent directory contains one.

Comment: " the same as the first on most systems" - I highly doubt this (that most systems have this alias). Instead, naked "rake" will invoke that from global gem list, not from this app's bundle.

Comment: actually there is some truth to this answer. Rvm does indeed fudge the path so that `rake ...` runs your project binaries. In fact there is a plugin for rbenv which allow you to do the same. `which` points to RVM/rbenv which in turn points to bin although recent recommendations suggest pointing bundler at .bundle/bin as rails has it's own scripts.