# Ruby on Rails migration rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After `rake db:migrate` I get this:

> `Gem::LoadError`: You have already activated rake 11.2.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 11.1.2.

What should I do?

Comment: Isn't there a duplicate for this question, I think it's a common problem.

Comment: @Marc-Andre find one and I’ll mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588674/what-does-bundle-exec-rake-mean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275885/use-bundle-exec-rake-or-just-rake have good information as to why you must do 'bundle exec', but it's not specifically about a gem version problem.

Comment: I'll keep this question in mind for future reference of this problem. It's a good clear enough question to be a good duplicate target.

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Basically the problem is that your local (`rvm` / `rbenv` / system) `rake` is of version `11.2.2`. You might consider downgrading it with `gem` as well.